# Three-colour theorem

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Three-coloring claims "A cubic map can be colored with only three colors if and only if each interior region has an even number of neighboring regions." and gives an example with US states:

[image: Proof without words]

Is each landlocked region having an even number of neighbours (plus missed by the article, exactly one neighbour i.e. completely surrounded) a sufficient condition to colour a general map (without enclaves or exclaves) in only three colours?

Answer (score 3):

As demonstrated by the map of US states, it is clearly a necessary condition (it is not difficult to write a proof for general maps by looking at the map). So is it sufficient if the map isn't necessarily cubic? If we go one paragraph up from your quote in the Wikipedia article, we encounter

> [It] is NP-complete in complexity to decide whether an arbitrary planar map can be colored with just three colors.

Checking the parity of the number of neighbours of each region is way below NP complete in complexity. So it cannot be sufficient.

Comment: Either that, or you have actually found a proof of P = NP. And I refuse to believe that a proof would be this easy to find.

Comment: Sorry, layman here. I don't understand "Checking the parity of the number of neighbours of each region is way below NP complete in complexity". Why can't we iterate each landlocked region and count the number of neighbours?

Comment: @Gnubie We can. But it is way too quick and easy to be a solution to an NP complete problem. So it can't be the solution.